How to bump tomcat-coyote and tomcat-catalina from version 7 to version 8+?
I am working on the fork of guacamole-client
I (and also original project) has depedencies:
<!-- Tomcat servlet API (websocket)  -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.109</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.109</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

And they used here:
public abstract class GuacamoleWebSocketTunnelServlet extends WebSocketServlet {
    ...
}

The issue that the versions are outdated and contain a bunch of vulnerabilities. I want to migrate to a newer version but I can't find any migration guide. Could you please give a piece of advice ? or point me out to correct documentation section
P.S. I start application using tomcat 9.
P.P.S.
I tried to bump to 8.0.1:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

As a result I see that those imports aren't resolved:
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.StreamInbound; 
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet; 
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.WsOutbound;

Also I've found this document where mentioned that those classes are removed in tomcat 8 and

Replaced by the JSR356 WebSocket 1.1 implementation and will be
removed in Tomcat 8.0.x.

Is there any migration guide for that ?

This may be an obvious question, but have you upgraded the version numbers in your POM dependencies (examples)? What happened if/when you tried? Did you hit a specific problem you can share?

There are also Tomcat changelogs you can refer to: Tomcat 8 and Tomcat 9, etc. Breaking changes (if there are any) may be documented there.

@andrewJames
Yes, sure I tried. For example when I bumped tomcat-catalina and tomcat-coyote dependencies to 8.0.1 those imports became broken:
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.StreamInbound;
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet;
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.WsOutbound;

@andrewJames Is there any relation between tomcat servlet container  version(now I use tomcat 9) and version of dependency of tomcat-catalina and tomcat-coyote ? (now it is 7 as you can see and it works)  ?

You may have all this info already, but...: From Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8, they removed their proprietary websockets code and standardized on JSR356 (as you note). But this is not covered in any detail in the related migration guide. You can look at the how-to guide, ...

...and also at the (latest) examples for server-side and client-side websocket examples code - bearing in mind that for Tomcat 8 you still need to use javax packages, not jakarta. Apart from that, I assume you need to completely re-write the Tomcat websocket code in Guacamole Client. That's about all I know.
